# Push my project to GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I'm using Git for the first time, some one can help me, I have user name, password and project repository, and I would push my project to Gitlabto this repository using windows 7.
Thanks

Comment: Great to hear that you're starting to learn Git, its extremely useful. Stack Overflow may not be the best place for a general question like this, I would try learning as much as you can from around the internet and then come here with specific questions. 

Check out this great git tutorial from Atlassian:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/

Answer (score 12):

If you have an empty Git repo declared (see [Create Project](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/gitlab-basics/create-project.md)), you can go to your local project and:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/project:
git init .
git add -A .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin https://<myLogin>@<mygitlab>/<mylogin>/<myproject>
git push -u -f origin master 
#The -f flag stands for force. This will automatically overwrite everything in the remote directory. We're only using it here to overwrite the README that GitHub automatically initialized.
```

Note: to get Git, simply uncompress [`PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.5.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want and add `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit\cmd` to your `%PATH%`.

Comment: Should be git remote add origin https://<myLogin>@<mygitlab>/<mylogin>/<myproject>

Comment: @Amansharma Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.